# Curl API and command line options to Authenticate with user name & password enabled https url

Tags: c, linux, curl

I am trying to authenticate against a HTTPS URL with "user name and password" using C-based curl API's and curl command line arguments in linux (`Fedora 14 curl 7.30.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0 zlib/1.2.5`) [image]) platform.

When I use the URL in the Mozilla web browser it prompts for the username, password once - after I press "OK" I am able to get the content. But if I press the cancel button, "Login Cancelled by User" is shown. The error (screenshot) is attached.

How to authenticate and avoid "Login cancelled by user" exception using curl API's and command line arguments?

Below are the options I have tried, but still the error remains the same - "Login cancelled by user"

Command Line:

```
curl -k --user "xxxxx:xxxxx" "https://fsgpos.opensoft.co.bw/ipa/statement/get/LN001234"
```

Curl API:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME,"xxxxxxxx");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD,"xxxxxxxx");
```

How to handle this exception with valid curl options and API arguments?

Comment: In order to understand what happens it probably would pay out for you to investigate how this http basic authentication actually works. Read about it, use a sniffer or debugging proxy to actually see the communication. Understanding things instead of blindly following an advice is very important to be able to learn new things, to analyse and find bugs, to really be able to code.

Comment: yes finally found it.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UserAgent` string with your curl. This is the only thing you are missing compare to the browser.

```
    -A "Mozilla 6.0"
```

Also, add the `-v` parameter also, and show us the debug message of curl.

Comment: I have posted the log and found it is self signed certificate. Also shows 401 unauthorized error & certificate expired error.

Comment: @user1495372 You didn't add `-A "Mozilla 6.0"` with the curl. The log says so. Please add that with your curl. And also, do not edit my post. Please edit your question :-)

Comment: I have tried [curl  -k "https://fsgpos.opensoft.co.bw/api/statement/get/LN001234" --user "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx" -A "Mozilla 6.0" ] with option but still same error appears. I dont think so this SSL error.It is only because of username and password...!any clue ?

Comment: @user1495372 you have used semicolon(`;`) before the `--user` in your command. Remove that and try again!

Comment: OK...That was copy and paste mistake...Issue resolved by adding --digest option in command line ,API is curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_DIGEST); We have to specify the curl for authentication method.Now it works fine...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST http://<auth url> --user "<username>:<password>" -c ~/cookies
```

- -c optionally store login in cookies

Comment: you'll have to look into how your authentication is set up in this case + it would help checking the web server logs for more information.

Comment: Issue resolved by adding --digest option in command line ,API is curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_DIGEST); We have to specify the curl for authentication method.Now it works fine...Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing client cert, client key and root cert

```
curl_easy_setopt(pcurlHandle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, clientcertfile);

curl_easy_setopt(pcurlHandle, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, clientkeyfile);

curl_easy_setopt(pcurlHandle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, rootcertfile);
```

Your code would be helpful to debug.

Comment: Issue resolved by adding --digest option in command line ,API is curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_DIGEST); We have to specify the curl for authentication method.Now it works fine...Thank you..